# How do you unlock rank 2 and 3 alchemy recipes in World of Warcraft: Battle for Azeroth?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I recently got into Zandalar, and saw that I have new potions for alchemy. There are rank 2 and 3 of these potions, how do I unlock the ranks for them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Rank 1 recipes are not special and simply allow you to craft the
  item. You can learn Rank 1 recipes from your profession trainer.
- Rank 2 recipes lower the amount of reagents needed for crafting. Most Rank 2 recipes can be purchased from the Alchemy trainer once
  you reach a high enough skill level, however some such as Mystical
  Cauldron are acquired differently.
- Rank 3 recipes have a chance to create multiple extra items at no extra cost. They are harder to obtain, often coming from faction
  vendors that require a certain reputation level before you can learn
  it.

[Source](https://www.wowhead.com/bfa-alchemy-guide)

Comment: Thank you, I was unware that the rank 2 needed a certain level, I thought it may have been from making the potion or a rep lock.

Answer (score 9):

Hold your mouse over the stars of the rank in the recipe's window and the tooltip tells you where to obtain the next rank and what the ranks do. This way you don't have to search for every single recipe.

[image]

Comment: Side note: How do you get all your other alchemy's to auto collapse? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You click the +/- sign beside the category.

Comment: @Sorean I do this, but when I close my alchemy tab and re-open they are expanded. Does it not 'save' your choice?

Comment: @Childishforlife probably a bug then.

Comment: That or an addon is causing the problem.